# Using Weblogic Data source in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datasource, weblogic-10.x

I use data source from Weblogic in Spring Boot project. In application.properties, I added data source jndi name `spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc/student`. But I got `NoInitialContextException`.

When I tried at the following, it works.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I would like to know how to override the default `InitialContext` information. I want to update weblogic server information such as `t3://127.0.0.1:7001`, `username` and `password`.